# Invalid CSS selector :not()

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have something like this:

```
ul.select.open li:first-child:not(li ul) a
```

And i´m getting a warning on my console. Why is not valid? It works for what i see on my site, that´s it, i apply the style for first child list anchor but not over anchors on sub-child lists.

I wish to understand why is invalid but works anyway.

Comment: what browser/version?

Comment: `li:first-child:not(li ul)` doesn't make sense since a `ul` could never be a `li`. I doubt that is what the browser is complaining about though.

Comment: Musa, well i supposed the :not will not apply for any li ul inside the li:first-child. I´m wrong there? Anyway as i said, in real life it works seeing it on chrome, firefox, safari.... that´s not the problem.

Comment: The `:not` applies to the `li:first-child`, just as the `:first-child` applies to the `li`.

Comment: Hypothetically, if `:not()` allowed combinators then `li:first-child:not(li ul)` would indeed match exactly the same things as `li:first-child` because the `:not()` condition becomes redundant. But it does not, so this selector should not work at all in CSS - where are you using it?

Comment: You should post a real demo (with HTML markup and a CSS rule that sets something), if you think that “it works”. What you see is most probably the effect of some completely different rule.

Comment: Also please specify which warning you get on which browser(s). Firefox issues a warning that says the rule is ignored due to invalid selector, which is what happens on other browsers, too.

Answer (score 4):

It is not valid, because in a [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), `:not(X)`, `X` must be a simple selector, and `ul li` is not. Conforming browsers are required to ignore a rule with an invalid selector, so if the rule somehow works, consider it a browser bug.

Comment: So that´s not the way to do what i want, since i need to apply a style only for anchors on parent list, but not on child ones, i mean, if you have a list inside a LI. Any ideas, i´ve also tryied using >, but i can´t get it.

Comment: I have answered the question why the construct is invalid. The construct does not actually work (please show a demo if you think otherwise), so the question why it works anyway isn’t real. If you want to ask how to style something specific, then that’s a different question. So I think you should accept this answer and ask a new question with sufficient details (verbal description of what you wish to style, a question title reflecting *that*, and sample HTML markup showing what the setup really is). The answer would greatly depend on the specific markup structure.